# What is a freestanding colon in C++

Tags: c++

The canonical Qt example is:

```
class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int m_value;
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
};
```

Qt defines the macro:

```
#define slots /* nothing */
```

After the preprocessor runs, we'd be left with:

```
public slots:
  void setValue(int value);
:
  void valueChanged(int newValue);
};
```

What what be the effect of the freestanding colon?  Can I add a colon anywhere I want?

```
int main() {
:
std::cout << "hi";
:
return 0;
}
```

What does a freestanding colon do in C++, and why is it allowed?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think you'd be left with `:` and not `public:`?

Comment: It looks to me like `signals:` gets turned into `public:`, not `:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No freestanding `:` are not allowed in `C` and `C++`.

`signals` is defined as `public`, so

```
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
```

would be pre-processed to

```
public:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
```

So there is not free colon.

Now slots is defined as nothing so

```
public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
```

would be replaced with (after comments are replaced with whitespace.

```
public :
    void setValue(int value);
```